# OCaml toplevel multiple dependencies

Tags: ocaml

When I have multiple dependencies, say

```
module A = struct
  open B
  ...
  end

module B = struct
  ...
  end
```

Is it possible to let the OCaml toplevel/utop load A.ml with all dependencies (i.e.`#use "./A.ml"` automatically loads B.ml)?

Comment: Can you be more precise ? By load do you mean `#use A.ml` ?

Comment: Exactly. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compile all your modules with ocamlc to produce the files `a.cmo` and `b.cmo` and then run `ocaml b.cmo a.cmo` (the order is important because `B` must be loaded before `A`).

Comment: So, just to make sure I'm understanding—the answer to "how can I make the OCaml repl load dependencies automatically" is "you can't; you must pass them as command-line flags in the proper order, and there is no tool to do this automatically"?